# QT Necessitas - cryptic ctype_base.h errors when linking gnu-libstdc++

Tags: android, linux, qt, stl, android-ndk

I started a Qt Mobile Application project in the Necessitas version of Qt Creator, targeting API 15 specifically. From there, I had some C++ sources I had written in Eclipse which I added to the project. Of course, there were a lot of undefined reference errors (due to the nature of Qt Necessitas not looking in the OS' include/lib path by default), so I did some Googling and founda  fix for that.

NOW, after that appears to be working I appear to get some weird errors which deal with GNU's stlport for Android/ARM.

Googled around for that as well, and found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-platform/lPdIzWUNlRs). If you read the last post, the OP was pretty stumped at the end and had a hard time figuring out the problem. My error appears to be a little different, but still relatively up the same ally as his/hers.

Basically, I could really use some guidance on how to figure this problem out. If anyone has any idea or has ran into the same issue regarding this, I'd really appreciate the advice!

At the bottom is pastebin for ctype_base.h.

Thank you!

**On to the Problem**

So, because I'm linking gnu-libstdc++ (the `.so` version, AFAIK), I have received the following errors in `ctype_base.h`:

```
/opt/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/libs/armeabi/include/bits/ctype_base.h:44: error: '_U' was not declared in this scope
/opt/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/libs/armeabi/include/bits/ctype_base.h:45: error: '_L' was not declared in this scope
/opt/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/libs/armeabi/include/bits/ctype_base.h:46: error: '_U' was not declared in this scope
/opt/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/libs/armeabi/include/bits/ctype_base.h:46: error: '_L' was not declared in this scope
/opt/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/libs/armeabi/include/bits/ctype_base.h:47: error: '_N' was not declared in this scope
/opt/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/libs/armeabi/include/bits/ctype_base.h:48: error: '_X' was not declared in this scope
/opt/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/libs/armeabi/include/bits/ctype_base.h:48: error: '_N' was not declared in this scope
/opt/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/libs/armeabi/include/bits/ctype_base.h:49: error: '_S' was not declared in this scope
/opt/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/libs/armeabi/include/bits/ctype_base.h:50: error: '_P' was not declared in this scope
/opt/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/libs/armeabi/include/bits/ctype_base.h:50: error: '_U' was not declared in this scope
/opt/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/libs/armeabi/include/bits/ctype_base.h:50: error: '_L' was not declared in this scope
/opt/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/libs/armeabi/include/bits/ctype_base.h:50: error: '_N' was not declared in this scope
/opt/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/libs/armeabi/include/bits/ctype_base.h:50: error: '_B' was not declared in this scope
/opt/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/libs/armeabi/include/bits/ctype_base.h:51: error: '_P' was not declared in this scope
/opt/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/libs/armeabi/include/bits/ctype_base.h:51: error: '_U' was not declared in this scope
/opt/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/libs/armeabi/include/bits/ctype_base.h:51: error: '_L' was not declared in this scope
/opt/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/libs/armeabi/include/bits/ctype_base.h:51: error: '_N' was not declared in this scope
/opt/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/libs/armeabi/include/bits/ctype_base.h:52: error: '_C' was not declared in this scope
/opt/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/libs/armeabi/include/bits/ctype_base.h:53: error: '_P' was not declared in this scope
/opt/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/libs/armeabi/include/bits/ctype_base.h:54: error: '_U' was not declared in this scope
/opt/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/libs/armeabi/include/bits/ctype_base.h:54: error: '_L' was not declared in this scope
/opt/android-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/libs/armeabi/include/bits/ctype_base.h:54: error: '_N' was not declared in this scope
```

Because Qt's Necessitas NDK seemed a couple of versions behind, I decided to just roll with the latest that I had received. Of course, Necessitas isn't fully stable yet (still in Alpha 3, IIRC), so I can't expect much, but after having some really unnecessary buggy experiences in Eclipse, I'd really hate to have to go back to there again. Don't get me wrong, if you're doing Java development, it's definitely the way to go. Just...not for C++ ;)

**Here's my `.pro` file as well:**

```
# Add files and directories to ship with the application 
# by adapting the examples below.
# file1.source = myfile
# dir1.source = mydir
DEPLOYMENTFOLDERS = # file1 dir1

symbian:TARGET.UID3 = 0xED47BA19

# Smart Installer package's UID
# This UID is from the protected range 
# and therefore the package will fail to install if self-signed
# By default qmake uses the unprotected range value if unprotected UID is defined for the application
# and 0x2002CCCF value if protected UID is given to the application
#symbian:DEPLOYMENT.installer_header = 0x2002CCCF

# Allow network access on Symbian
symbian:TARGET.CAPABILITY += NetworkServices

# If your application uses the Qt Mobility libraries, uncomment
# the following lines and add the respective components to the 
# MOBILITY variable. 
# CONFIG += mobility
# MOBILITY +=

SOURCES += main.cpp mainwindow.cpp \
    GLTriangleDemo.cpp \
    Debug.cpp \
    Shader.cpp
HEADERS += mainwindow.h \
    GLincludes.hpp \
    GLDemo.hpp \
    Entry.hpp \
    Debug.hpp \
    Triangle.hpp \
    Shape.hpp \
    Shader.hpp \
    GLTriangleDemo.hpp
FORMS += mainwindow.ui

#includes

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include

#external deps
external_libs.files += /usr/lib

x86 {
      external_libs.path = /libs/x86
} else: armeabi-v7a {
      external_libs.path = /libs/armeabi-v7a
} else {
      external_libs.path = /libs/armeabi
}

INSTALLS += external_libs

LIBS += -llog -lGLESv2 -lgnustl_shared

# Please do not modify the following two lines. Required for deployment.
include(deployment.pri)
qtcAddDeployment()

OTHER_FILES += \
    android/res/values-ja/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-it/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-pt-rBR/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-el/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-nl/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-ro/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-id/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-fr/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-rs/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-de/strings.xml \
    android/res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png \
    android/res/values-pl/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-ru/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-es/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-ms/strings.xml \
    android/res/values/strings.xml \
    android/res/values/libs.xml \
    android/res/drawable/icon.png \
    android/res/drawable/logo.png \
    android/res/values-zh-rTW/strings.xml \
    android/res/layout/splash.xml \
    android/res/values-fa/strings.xml \
    android/res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png \
    android/res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png \
    android/res/values-nb/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-zh-rCN/strings.xml \
    android/res/values-et/strings.xml \
    android/version.xml \
    android/AndroidManifest.xml \
    android/src/org/kde/necessitas/origo/QtApplication.java \
    android/src/org/kde/necessitas/origo/QtActivity.java \
    android/src/org/kde/necessitas/ministro/IMinistroCallback.aidl \
    android/src/org/kde/necessitas/ministro/IMinistro.aidl
```

And, here's a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/C1ESwgu3) of ctype_base.h

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue. In my case it seems that the problem was caused by environment variables, namely "CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH" and "C_INCLUDE_PATH". These variables contained paths to my system C++ includes which, I guess, were interfering with the armabi platform includes.

Solution : I simply unset those two env. variables.

Redgis

PS: I edidted my previous answer but still marked as "deleted", so I repost. Doesn't fill right to me to do so, but I don't see another way to post my contribution.

Comment: Thanks, man. When I get back into Android development I'll refer to this.